# Replace org-open-link-from-string failure format

Tags: org-mode, auctex, reftex-mode

I'm not even sure I'm asking the right question, but here goes: I followed [this guide](https://tincman.wordpress.com/2011/01/04/research-paper-management-with-emacs-org-mode-and-reftex/) which introduces a function to search an org-mode file for a reftex/bibtex key and jump to that position in the file. The function is as follows:

```
(defun org-mode-reftex-search ()
  ;;jump to the notes for the paper pointed to at from reftex search
  (interactive)
  (org-open-link-from-string (format "[[notes:%s]]" (first (reftex-citation t)))))
```

When I use the function and search reftex for a file that is in the buffer, everything works beautifully. When I search for a file that is not in the buffer, however, I get asked `No match - create this as a new heading? (y or n)`. If I say `y`, a new top level entry is put into the buffer with the format:

```
* #BibtexKey
```

The problem is that I've taken the time to set up a better format for new entries in my org-mode notes file. What I would like is to use that format when the entry doesn't already exist. The format I'm using, again from that tutorial, is:

```
** %t
  :PROPERTIES:
  :Custom_ID: %l
  :END:
```

Where %t is the title of the paper and %l is the Bibtex key. How do I replace the default format of a reftex search?

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a new heading is actually done by `org-link-search`.  The
relevant part of the function (currently) looks like this:

```
((and (not org-link-search-inhibit-query)
      (eq org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline 'query-to-create)
      (y-or-n-p "No match - create this as a new heading? "))
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (unless (bolp) (newline))
    (org-insert-heading nil t t)
    (insert s "\n")
    (beginning-of-line 0))
```

So there is no easy way to hook into it and produce the format you
want.  You can set `org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline` to t,
but then you'll have to make the heading manually, so that doesn't get
you to where you want.  One option is to catch the error after calling
`org-open-link-from-string` (with
`org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline` set to t).  Here's one
(maybe not-so-elegant) way to do that.

```
(defun org-mode-reftex-search ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((reftex-default-bibliography
         (mapcar #'expand-file-name reftex-default-bibliography))
        tree key)
    (setq tree
          (with-temp-buffer
            (let ((reftex-cite-format "** %t\n  :PROPERTIES:\n  :CUSTOM_ID: %l\n  :END:\n[[papers:%l][%l-paper]]"))
              (setq key (car (reftex-citation)))
              (buffer-string))))
    (condition-case nil
        (let ((org-link-search-must-match-exact-headline t))
          (org-open-link-from-string (format "file:/tmp/notes.org::#%s" key)))
      (error
       (with-current-buffer (get-file-buffer "/tmp/notes.org")
         (goto-char (point-max))
         (unless (bolp) (newline))
         (insert tree)
         (org-back-to-heading))))))
```

I think the only thing you should have to modify in the code above is the path to your notes.

Comment: Running this gives me: `No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available`. I define the bibliography at the top of the notes.org file with `# \bibliography{refs.bib}`.